# O Tooltip do Bootstrap 4 não funciona corretamente no Angular 6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, template, tooltip

Abaixo segue a implementação do bootstrap na minha aplicação (angular.json)

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

No component.html está assim:

```
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col">
      <label for="AccountName" ***data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"***>Account Name</label>
      <input class="form-control isRequired" formControlName="AccountName" type="text" id="AccountName">
      <small *ngIf="formAmendment.get('AccountName').errors?.required" class="text-danger d-block mt-2">Account Name is required!</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

E é assim que está aparecendo na tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolvo isso?

Comment: Uma forma rápida e fácil de resolver qualquer problema com o bootstrap é instalar o ng-bootstrap. 

Rode: npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap e pronto

Documentação: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Cara tem uns detalhes ai.

Primeiro vc tem que iniciar o script `Tooltipe`, não sei se vc está fazendo isso. Aqui está a documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/

Segundo. Esses asteriscos estão sendo incluído na string tipo `***data-toggle="tooltip"` isso `***` não pode ficar colocado em `data`, pois dessa forma o browser entendo como uma palava só!

Veja no exemplo abaixo funcionando no primeiro elemento e *buggando* no segundo por causa do *****

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    
        <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">
                  <label for="AccountName" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Account Name</label>
                  <input class="form-control isRequired" formControlName="AccountName" type="text" id="AccountName">
                  <small *ngIf="formAmendment.get('AccountName').errors?.required" class="text-danger d-block mt-2"> * esse não funciona!</small>
                </div>
              </div>
              
                      <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">
                  <label for="AccountName" *data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Account Name</label>
                  <input class="form-control isRequired" formControlName="AccountName" type="text" id="AccountName">
                  <small *ngIf="formAmendment.get('AccountName').errors?.required" class="text-danger d-block mt-2">Account Name is required!</small>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tooltip em Angular**

Adicionar

### placement="top" ngbTooltip="Texto a ser mostrar"

ao invés de ***data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"***